# How do I suspend and resume a WSL1 process in PowerShell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In bash, a job can be suspended with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and resumed it with `fg`. Bash in Windows Subsystem for Linux 1 (WSL1) also supports this. However, PowerShell doesn't naitively support suspended jobs, and doesn't interact well with this feature by default.

For instance, if I run `wsl -e vi`, a vi editor opens. If I then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, vi is suspended, but PowerShell becomes unresponsive. It doesn't print a prompt, or respond to any input, until the suspensed process is killed. Apparently, PowerShell doesn't know what to do with a suspended processes.

How can I get PowerShell to respond after suspending a WSL1 process in it, and resume the process later? Possible solutions might include changing PowerShell's configuration, or wrapping wsl invocations to intercept <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and emulate the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Below are two methods for suspending  PowerShell commands.
However, they will not liberate the console as is the case under Linux.

**Method 1 : Debug mode**

While in the  PowerShell console, you may suspend the currently executing command/script
by entering Debug mode.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> to enter Debug mode.
Enter the command `Continue` to continue executing.

**Method 2 : Using Suspend-Job**

When using two PowerShell consoles, you may give a command a name
with the `-JobName` parameter, then to suspend issue in the other console the command
`Suspend-Job -Name myname`.

References:

- [Suspend-Job](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/suspend-job)
- [Resume-Job](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/resume-job)